# Rich Text Format to Plain Text

Tags: java, html, swing, rtf

I am trying to convert RTF to PTF using Swing's `RTFEditorKit`. This is my code.

Example RTF content is -

```html
<p>4th Review Information for Bug Id DRRaa50524 </p>
 <h5 style="text-align: center;">4th Review Information for Bug Id DRRaa50524</h5>
 <h2 style="text-align: right;">4th Review Information for Bug Id DRRaa50524</h2>
```

But I am getting document length as 0 and text as empty. What is wrong with my code?

```
public String RTFToPTConverter(String des) throws Exception {
    RTFEditorKit rtfParser = new RTFEditorKit();
    Document document = rtfParser.createDefaultDocument();
    rtfParser.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(des.getBytes()), document, 0);
    System.out.println(document.getLength());
    String text = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
    System.out.println(text);
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your text is [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), not [RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format). Use HTMLEditorKit to work with it.

```
HTMLEditorKit htmlParser = new HTMLEditorKit();
Document document = htmlParser.createDefaultDocument();
htmlParser.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(des.getBytes()), document, 0);
```